# How to add lines to code in visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

How do I get lines in my Visual Studio like in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various extensions that add this functionality.

[Indent Guides](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30?SRC=VSIDE) is one